# Remove complex part of a solution

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I have a function `intSL[a,zl,zh]` where I want to compute its derivative with respect to `zl` given some values of `a` and `zh`. I also want to plot it wrt to `zl` with the range `0 < zl < 1`.

However, there are some `zl` where my function displays an error message and produces a complex value. When I compare results that are complex valued to the result that are not, it seems like their corresponding real parts has a trend and so I think I could just eliminate the imaginary part (I think???), but I do not know how to do it.

Here is my code,

```
d = 3;
torootL[a_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ, zl_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := a - NIntegrate[(zl y^d)/Sqrt[(1 - (zl/zh)^(d + 1) y^(d + 1)) (1 + t^2 (1 - (zl/zh)^(d + 1))^-1 - y^(2 d))], {y, 0, 1}]
tz[a_?NumericQ, zl_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := t /. FindRoot[torootL[a, t, zl, zh], {t, 1, -1000, 10000}]
intSL[a_?NumericQ, zl_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[With[{b = zl/zh}, (((-1)/(d - 1)) (zl^(2 d) (1 + tz[a, zl, zh]^2 (1 - (zl/zh)^(d + 1))^(-1)))^(-1) zl^(2 d)) x^d ((1 - (b x)^(d + 1))/(1 - (zl^(2 d) (1 + tz[a, zl, zh]^2 (1 - (zl/zh)^(d + 1))^(-1)))^(-1) (zl x)^(2 d)))^(1/2) - ((b^(d + 1) (d + 1))/(2 (d - 1))) x ((1 - (zl^(2 d) (1 + tz[a, zl, zh]^2 (1 - (zl/zh)^(d + 1))^(-1)))^(-1) (zl x)^(2 d))/(1 - (b x)^(d + 1)))^(1/2) + (b^(d + 1)x)/((1 - (b x)^(d + 1)) (1 - (zl^(2 d) (1 + tz[a, zl, zh]^2 (1 - (zl/zh)^(d + 1))^(-1)))^(-1) (zl x)^(2 d)))^(1/2)], {x, 0, 0.98, 0.99, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 20, PrecisionGoal -> 6]
```

Here is an example of the evaluation of the derivative,

```
intSLL[zl_] := Evaluate[D[intSL[0.01, zl, 1], zl]]

In[58]:= intSLL[0.3]

During evaluation of In[58]:= FindRoot::jsing: Encountered a singular Jacobian at the point {t} = {-5.99038*10^-9}. Try perturbing the initial point(s).

During evaluation of In[58]:= FindRoot::jsing: Encountered a singular Jacobian at the point {t} = {-5.99038*10^-9}. Try perturbing the initial point(s).

During evaluation of In[58]:= FindRoot::jsing: Encountered a singular Jacobian at the point {t} = {-5.99038*10^-9}. Try perturbing the initial point(s).

During evaluation of In[58]:= General::stop: Further output of FindRoot::jsing will be suppressed during this calculation.

During evaluation of In[58]:= FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

During evaluation of In[58]:= FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

During evaluation of In[58]:= FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

During evaluation of In[58]:= General::stop: Further output of FindRoot::lstol will be suppressed during this calculation.

During evaluation of In[58]:= FindRoot::reged: The point {10000.} is at the edge of the search region {-1000.,10000.} in coordinate 1 and the computed search direction points outside the region.

During evaluation of In[58]:= FindRoot::reged: The point {10000.} is at the edge of the search region {-1000.,10000.} in coordinate 1 and the computed search direction points outside the region.

During evaluation of In[58]:= FindRoot::reged: The point {10000.} is at the edge of the search region {-1000.,10000.} in coordinate 1 and the computed search direction points outside the region.

During evaluation of In[58]:= General::stop: Further output of FindRoot::reged will be suppressed during this calculation.

Out[58]= 0.0149288

In[57]:= intSLL[0.4]

During evaluation of In[57]:= FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

During evaluation of In[57]:= FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

During evaluation of In[57]:= FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

During evaluation of In[57]:= General::stop: Further output of FindRoot::lstol will be suppressed during this calculation.

During evaluation of In[57]:= FindRoot::jsing: Encountered a singular Jacobian at the point {t} = {-6.30218*10^-9}. Try perturbing the initial point(s).

During evaluation of In[57]:= FindRoot::jsing: Encountered a singular Jacobian at the point {t} = {-6.30218*10^-9}. Try perturbing the initial point(s).

During evaluation of In[57]:= FindRoot::jsing: Encountered a singular Jacobian at the point {t} = {-6.30218*10^-9}. Try perturbing the initial point(s).

During evaluation of In[57]:= General::stop: Further output of FindRoot::jsing will be suppressed during this calculation.

During evaluation of In[57]:= FindRoot::reged: The point {10000.} is at the edge of the search region {-1000.,10000.} in coordinate 1 and the computed search direction points outside the region.

During evaluation of In[57]:= FindRoot::reged: The point {10000.} is at the edge of the search region {-1000.,10000.} in coordinate 1 and the computed search direction points outside the region.

During evaluation of In[57]:= FindRoot::reged: The point {10000.} is at the edge of the search region {-1000.,10000.} in coordinate 1 and the computed search direction points outside the region.

During evaluation of In[57]:= General::stop: Further output of FindRoot::reged will be suppressed during this calculation.

Out[57]= 0.00650273

In[55]:= intSLL[0.5]

Out[55]= 0.00353467

In[56]:= intSLL[0.6]

During evaluation of In[56]:= FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

During evaluation of In[56]:= FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

During evaluation of In[56]:= FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

During evaluation of In[56]:= General::stop: Further output of FindRoot::lstol will be suppressed during this calculation.

During evaluation of In[56]:= NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in y near {y} = {0.984824086012257}. NIntegrate obtained 0.0293841 -0.119444 I and 0.0017267736029825806` for the integral and error estimates.

During evaluation of In[56]:= NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in y near {y} = {0.984824086012257}. NIntegrate obtained 0.0293841 -0.119444 I and 0.0017267736029825806` for the integral and error estimates.

During evaluation of In[56]:= NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in y near {y} = {0.984824086012257}. NIntegrate obtained 0.0293841 -0.119444 I and 0.001726773577114529` for the integral and error estimates.

During evaluation of In[56]:= General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::ncvb will be suppressed during this calculation.

During evaluation of In[56]:= FindRoot::reged: The point {1.} is at the edge of the search region {-1000.,10000.} in coordinate 1 and the computed search direction points outside the region.

During evaluation of In[56]:= FindRoot::reged: The point {1.} is at the edge of the search region {-1000.,10000.} in coordinate 1 and the computed search direction points outside the region.

During evaluation of In[56]:= FindRoot::reged: The point {1.} is at the edge of the search region {-1000.,10000.} in coordinate 1 and the computed search direction points outside the region.

During evaluation of In[56]:= General::stop: Further output of FindRoot::reged will be suppressed during this calculation.

During evaluation of In[56]:= NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

During evaluation of In[56]:= NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

During evaluation of In[56]:= NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

During evaluation of In[56]:= General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::slwcon will be suppressed during this calculation.

Out[56]= 0.00225041 + 8.62966*10^-11 I

In[59]:= intSLL[0.7]

During evaluation of In[59]:= NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

During evaluation of In[59]:= NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in y near {y} = {0.99762205831973036103399454788132061366923153400421142578125000000}. NIntegrate obtained 0.00330503 -0.0437457 I and 0.0008224862881109875` for the integral and error estimates.

During evaluation of In[59]:= NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

During evaluation of In[59]:= NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in y near {y} = {0.99762205831973036103399454788132061366923153400421142578125000000}. NIntegrate obtained 0.00330503 -0.0437457 I and 0.0008224862881109875` for the integral and error estimates.

During evaluation of In[59]:= NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

During evaluation of In[59]:= General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::slwcon will be suppressed during this calculation.

During evaluation of In[59]:= NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in y near {y} = {0.99762205831973036103399454788132061366923153400421142578125000000}. NIntegrate obtained 0.00330503 -0.0437457 I and 0.0008224862758539473` for the integral and error estimates.

During evaluation of In[59]:= General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::ncvb will be suppressed during this calculation.

During evaluation of In[59]:= FindRoot::reged: The point {1.} is at the edge of the search region {-1000.,10000.} in coordinate 1 and the computed search direction points outside the region.

During evaluation of In[59]:= FindRoot::reged: The point {1.} is at the edge of the search region {-1000.,10000.} in coordinate 1 and the computed search direction points outside the region.

During evaluation of In[59]:= FindRoot::reged: The point {1.} is at the edge of the search region {-1000.,10000.} in coordinate 1 and the computed search direction points outside the region.

During evaluation of In[59]:= General::stop: Further output of FindRoot::reged will be suppressed during this calculation.

Out[59]= 0.0016139 + 2.5821*10^-6 I
```

To summarize the sample result, `intSLL[zl]` produces the values for the corresponding `zl`

```
0.0149288                         zl=0.3   (with error)
0.00650273                        zl=0.4   (with error)
0.00353467                        zl=0.5
0.00225041 + 8.62966*10^-11 I     zl=0.6   (with error)
0.0016139 + 2.5821*10^-6 I        zl=0.7   (with error)
```

You can see the trend of the values of the real part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Derivative` instead of `D`:

```
{#, intSL[.01, #, 1], Derivative[0, 1, 0][intSL][0.01, # , 1]} &[.3]
(*{0.3, -0.00218296, 0.0149288}*)

{#, intSL[.01, #, 1], Derivative[0, 1, 0][intSL][0.01, # , 1]} &[.6];
% //Chop
(*{0.6, -0.000430944, 0.00225041}*)
```

The evaluation takes some time and shows several messages "FindRoot::jsing: Encountered a singular Jacobian at the point {t} = {-5.99038*10^-9}. Try perturbing the initial point(s)." but works in principle.

Comment: I tried your code for `zl=0.6`, it still displays the imaginary part. Also how does it work when you enclose those functions in a list `{}` then evaluate at `.3` using &?

Comment: For `zl=.6` Mathematica v12 evaluates `{0.6, -0.000430944, 0.00225041 + 8.62966*10^-11 I}`, the imaginary part might be removed with `Chop`

Comment: The code I used, `intSLL[zl_] := Evaluate[Derivative[0, 1, 0][intSL][0.01, zl, 1]]`. For `0.6` it worked In[81]:= `intSLL[0.6] // Chop // Quiet Out[81]= 0.00225041` but for `0.7` it did not, `In[84]:= intSLL[0.7] // Chop // Quiet Out[84]= 0.0016139 + 2.58281*10^-6 I`

Comment: Usually `Chop` works with a tolerance of `10^-10`, that's why imaginary part ` 2.58281*10^-6 I ` still apperars. Try `//Chop[#,10^-6]&`

Comment: Sorry for a naive question but how do I use your syntax `//Chop[#,10^-6]&` ? I used `Chop[intSLL[0.7], 10^-5] // Quiet` and it worked.

Comment: `Chop[intSLL[0.7], 10^-5]` and `intSLL[0.7] //Chop[#,10^-5]&` are the same!

Comment: I made some typo that is why it is not working, now it is ok. Thanks!